# xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, react-native

[image: terminal]

I was basically trying to create a new React Native project but my simulator won't open and terminal throws this error

Please help, what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 34):

**SOLUTION 1**

Go to this location

> Xcode > Preferences > Locations

And assigning the Command Line Tools

[image]

**SOLUTION 2**

In Terminal, try this.

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

**/Applications/Xcode.app** is your Xcode.app path.

Answer (score 7):

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

with `/Applications/Xcode.app` is your Xcode.app path.